# Slow performance when selecting features

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I am trying to use the following code to select the features that have the attribute values that I pass in. The performance is really slow when it comes to a lot of values e.g >16k values to match features.

Is there something I'm missing or a better way of doing this?

// Assuming values.Any() is true:

```c#
var featureSelection = (layer as IFeatureSelection);

var whereClause = new StringBuilder();
var count = 0;
while (true)
{
    var values = valuesToSelect.Skip(count*1000).Take(1000).ToList();
    if (!values.Any()) break;
    var thousandsClause = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        thousandsClause.Append(",");
        thousandsClause.Append(value);
    }
    thousandsClause.Remove(0, 1);
    thousandsClause.Insert(0, fieldName + " IN (");
    thousandsClause.Append(")");
    whereClause.Append(" OR " + thousandsClause);

    count++;
}
whereClause.Remove(0, 4);
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
queryFilter.WhereClause = whereClause.ToString();

featureSelection.SelectFeatures(queryFilter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);
featureSelection.SelectionChanged();
```

Sample WHERE IN clauses:

[761 values to select](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16821294/WhereOBJECTIDIN761Items.txt)

[122,072 values to select](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16821294/WhereOBJECTIDIN122072Items)

Edit--

So far with recommendations from some of the comments, I've improved the code and the results are faster but still not desirable. Here is the code I've begun trying using the same WHERE IN clause:

```c#
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
queryFilter.WhereClause = whereClause.ToString();
queryFilter.SubFields = "OBJECTID";

var featureLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer2;
if (featureLayer == null) continue;

IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
var dataset = (IDataset) featureClass;
IWorkspace workSpace = dataset.Workspace;
ISelectionSet selectionSet = featureClass
.Select(queryFilter, esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid,esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal,workSpace);

var featureSelection = layer as IFeatureSelection;
if (featureSelection != null)
{
    featureSelection.SelectionSet = selectionSet;
    featureSelection.SelectionChanged();
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the whereClause that is built with your code to your question?

Comment: I've edited the question with sample generated where in clauses @awesomo

Comment: Those links aren't working for me

Comment: @awesomo Tried both links from different networks and they work no problems.

Comment: If you're always querying objectid, it would be much faster to just use [ISelectionSet.AddList](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddList_Method/002500000805000000/).

Comment: Just remembered... I think my stupid network guy blocked drop box. However, one thing -- if they are so big that you need to put them on dropbox instead of posting them with question -- that's going to be part of the problem.

Comment: Hehe. The times that the items in the WHERE IN are few, then it performs okay. However, and why I've included a huge item list in a dropbox txt file, when SelectFeatures is hit with a huge WHERE clause, it falls down. @KirkKuykendall - it seems that that method is not to be used in .NET and I've tried to use the recommended helper class to no avail. Also it might not be the ObjectID at all times. This was just an example. Got an example how you'd go about using it with .AddList()?

Comment: have you tried selset.AddList(count,ref oids[0]) ?

Comment: In cases where you aren't querying oids, I think it would be easier to scan the featureclass to find the OIDs whose attribute appears in your list, then use the AddList method.  You can speed up the scan by using a queryfilter with a subfield that is your field of interest and specifying recycling=true when you open the cursor.  Also having the values of interest in a dictionary where you can call KeyExists might be faster than having them in a list and calling the Contains.

Comment: Is the attribute over which you are querying indexed?

Comment: @PetrKrebs this is not determinant at the moment. The user can use any dataset and it might not be indexed.

Comment: Do I have some access to the generated ArcMap SQL so that I could attempt to make a temporary table and do joins?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - I did try selectionSet.AddList(,) but the thing is I had to go through the cursor to retried the OID for each resulting feature and this was a bottleneck even before I hit selectionSet.AddList(,)

Comment: When retrieving OID's, did you set a queryfilter with subfield, and use recycling=true?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Yes I did. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're building a massive where clause which is causing your SQL to get testy. I would try to select each case in turn and then add to the selection set for each new case:

```
    ISelectionSet FinalSet = FeatureClass.Select(
    null,
    esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid,
    esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionEmpty,
    workSpace);

ISelectionSet Recycle;
IQueryFilter pQF = new QueryFilterClass();
while (true) 
{ // include here getting the value for each selection

    pQF.WhereClause = fieldName + " = " + value;
    Recycle = FeatureClass.Select(
        pQF,
        esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid,
        esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal,
        workSpace);
    FinalSet.Combine(Recycle,esriSetOperation.esriSetUnion,FinalSet);
}
```

This will do multiple small selections and accumulate them into the FinalSet then you can do your featureslection from the FinalSet.